# How do I right-align text?

Tags: xna, spritebatch, text

I'm using `SpriteBatch.DrawString`, which seems to not have an overload for text alignment. How can I draw aligned text?

Comment: You should mention what framework you're using.

Comment: It's probably XNA.

Comment: @Grey XNA and MonoGame typically are what would have a DrawString method like that, but you never know. :(

Comment: If you're using XNA, there's already a really good extension method written over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263734/how-to-align-text-drawn-by-spritebatch-drawstring

Comment: yes thnx, thats what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I created a [helper class](https://github.com/ClassicThunder/MonoGameGui/blob/master/Gui/Rendering/TextRenderer.cs) in [Ruminate MonoGame GUI](https://github.com/ClassicThunder/MonoGameGui/blob/master/ruminate-gui-monogame.csproj) that takes in the following arguments and lets you align or center the text within a Rectangle both vertically and horizontally. Passing in neither enum results in the same behavior as the default `SpriteBatch` function.

The options for the emuns are.

```
public enum TextHorizontal { LeftAligned, CenterAligned, RightAligned }
public enum TextVertical { TopAligned, CenterAligned, BottomAligned }
```

And the math in the function of interest is quite simple.

```
    public void Render(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, string value, Rectangle renderArea,
        TextHorizontal h = TextHorizontal.LeftAligned, TextVertical v = TextVertical.TopAligned) {

        var location = new Vector2(renderArea.X, renderArea.Y);

        var size = SpriteFont.MeasureString(value);

        switch (h) {
            case TextHorizontal.CenterAligned:
                location.X += (renderArea.Width - size.X) / 1.9f;
                break;
            case TextHorizontal.RightAligned:
                location.X += renderArea.Width - size.X;
                break;
        }

        switch (v) {
            case TextVertical.CenterAligned:
                location.Y += (renderArea.Height - size.Y) / 1.9f;
                break;
            case TextVertical.BottomAligned:
                location.Y += renderArea.Height - size.Y;
                break;
        }

        spriteBatch.DrawString(SpriteFont, value, location, Color);
    }
```

Comment: what is that magic / 1.9?

Comment: i think it shoudl be 2... maybe he uses 1.9 for some minor offset?